# java: Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY returns incorrect value. Why?

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, dst

The java code below:

```
Calendar calend = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone
                .getTimeZone("Pacific/Fakaofo"));

        System.out.println(calend.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                + calend.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + calend.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

*Actual result*: **2:21:19**

*Expected result*: **1:21:19** (http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=738).

Why does actual result contain one extra hour?

Comment: Daylight savings time?

Comment: What is the full date?

Comment: @Henrik, No daylight saving time in 2013

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Current date

Comment: What version of Java are you using, and what is the output of `System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Fakaofo").inDaylightTime(new Date()));`?

Comment: Which (full) Java version? Are you sure your local system time is correct? Maybe you are using an old version with an outdated TZ database (this timezone changed from UTC-11h to UTC+13h)

Comment: @VGR, java.version is: 1.6.0_24

Comment: @VGR, System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Fakaofo").inDaylightTime(new Date())); returns False.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, 370 people were physically present on Fakaofo during the last census. What are the chances that one of them is on StackOverflow, and could tell us what time it is?! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Pacific/Fakaofo Time Zone](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo.tzc?s=default&tz=Pacific/Fakaofo) it is

```
Wed 20-Mar-2013 02:31 A.M.
```

so your actual result seems correct.

[Tokelau: Wrong local time for over 100 years](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/tokelau-wrong-time.html) might be the answer. There seems to be some confusion about the real timezone.

Comment: @NPE Then I was just lucky ;-)

Comment: For all I know, the one you found could well be the only one that's correct :)